# Duplicated for specific column after grouping - Speed Issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I have working code below, which does what I am after, and does it fine for a test subset of +- 1.000 records. However, in the actual dataset, I have about half a million rows, where suddenly the code takes up over five minutes. Could anyone tell me why or how to improve the code?

The end result I need is to keep only the first value of duplicated ID's, but for each year this should be renewed (i.e. double values are fine if they are in different years, but not in the same year).

```
Test %>%
  group_by(year, id) %>%
  mutate(is_duplicate = duplicated(id)) %>%
  mutate(oppervlakt = ifelse(is_duplicate == FALSE, oppervlakt, 0))%>%
  select(-is_duplicate)
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicated records or turn them to 0?

Comment: Please show us some example data and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could remove `id` from grouping and should get same results. See this example:

```
library(dplyr)
# some sample data:
n_rows <- 1E6
df <- data.frame(year = sample(x = c(2000:2018), size = n_rows, replace = TRUE),
                 id = sample(x = seq_len(1000), size = n_rows, replace = TRUE),
                 oppervlakt = rnorm(n = n_rows))

# Roughly 1 second:
system.time(df_slow <- df %>% group_by(year, id) %>% mutate(oppervlakt = ifelse(duplicated(id), 0, oppervlakt)))

# Roughly .1 second:
system.time(df_fast <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(oppervlakt = ifelse(duplicated(id), 0, oppervlakt)))

all.equal(df_slow, df_fast)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. That does give the same results. Well spotted!